# Restarting PyQt QApplication that contains matplotlib canvas

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

You can see the window persists when using QApplicaiton.exit() and then crashes when it tries to restart the second time. Thought it could be a threading issue but it seems to still exist when I try more meticulous methods of closing the matplotlib canvas before exiting.

```
import sys
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    REBOOT_CODE = -654321
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.sc = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        self.sc.axes.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 1, 20, 3, 40])

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('reload', self)
        button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.reloadapp())

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(button)
        layout.addWidget(self.sc)

        # Create a placeholder widget
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)


    def reloadapp(self):
        self.sc.close_event()
        QtWidgets.QApplication.exit( MainWindow.REBOOT_CODE )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    exit_code = MainWindow.REBOOT_CODE
    while exit_code == MainWindow.REBOOT_CODE:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        w = MainWindow()
        w.show()
        app.exec_()
        app = None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that doing `app = None` does not eliminate the QApplication since in Python it is enough that another variable maintains the reference of the object so that it remains alive and that happens with matplotlib that maintains a reference of QApplication. One possible solution is to use sip.delete to delete the C++ object.

Another error is also that you do not assign what `app.exec_()` returns to `exit_code` which generates an infinite loop. On the other hand it is not necessary to use `self.sc.close_event ()`.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, sip
```

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    exit_code = MainWindow.REBOOT_CODE
    while exit_code == MainWindow.REBOOT_CODE:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        w = MainWindow()
        w.show()
        exit_code = app.exec_()
        sip.delete(app)
        app = None
```

Comment: sip did the trick!
Thanks so much for this! I had been stuck on this for ages. I had an idea this was more or less what was happening but scoured the internet for an answer and couldn't find one. I wish I had come here sooner!